# the meaning of Spring Kafka Listener Thread name?

Tags: java, spring, logback, spring-kafka

when I use spring kafka, I hava noticed my log just like this:

```
2021-01-16 17:07:25.795 [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-8-C-1] WARN  c.d.j.k.KafkaConsumer [listenerHomework:86]    - no message
```

and my logback encoder

```
<pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{15} [%M:%L] - %msg%n
```

`org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-8-C-1` is the thread name, I want to know  the meaning of `0-8-C-1`, or some else doc I can find?

Comment: I hava find the doc  https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#container-thread-naming, but it is not very clear

Answer (score 0):

The prefix `org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0` is a generated bean name . It is a standard Spring container behavior to generate bean names from their classes if no explicit name. The `8` means the consumer index in this container. `1` means that this consumer has been started only once .

Comment: If you give the `@KafkaListener` an `id` property, the thread name will be based on that.